# Can someone translate this badly written Perl code for me?

Tags: perl

I am needing to obtain the algorithm used in this little bit of Perl code, but I know nothing about Perl.  Usually that's not a problem since I will research the language, but this regular expression stuff is way over my head!

Could anybody pseudo-code this?  I just need to know what's going on so I can implement it in something else, preferably PHP or even C++, but I'll worry about that part.  I just need to somehow decipher what this is doing:

```
$a = $ARGV[0];
$a =~ s/[^A-F0-9]+//simg;
@b = reverse split /(\S{2})/,$a;
$c = join "", @b;
$c .= "0000";
$d = hex($c) % 999999929;
print "$d\n";
```

Comment: @Sinan, thanks for changing the title.  :)  It surely is poorly written, and I hoped would at least have been commented, but that's how it goes.

Comment: This doesn't look "badly written Perl code" to me, and if it does what it is supposed to do, then it's even well written code.

Comment: It is badly written because instead of extracting hex digits, it goes through a `s///` and then `split` with a first argument that is not obvious. Instead of using a bit-shift operation, it just concatenates zeros at the end. Even the `s///` is stupid. It should just be `s/[[:^xdigit:]]+//g`. The `/s` and `/m` options have no bearing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's poorly written about it? It could use a better var names, but I don't know if that's possible (since the intermediary steps don't appear to have any nameable quality), leaving only an improper use of `split`. The pseudo code is almost a word for word translation.

```
$a = $ARGV[0];
$a =~ s/[^A-F0-9]+//simg;
@b = reverse split /(\S{2})/,$a;
$c = join "", @b;
$c .= "0000";
$d = hex($c) % 999999929;
print "$d\n";
```

should be

```
$a = $ARGV[0];                # Get a hex str from cmd line   E3:C9:D4
$a =~ s/[^A-F0-9]+//simg;     # Remove any non-hex digits     E3C9D4
@b = reverse $a =~ /(..)/sg;  # Extract "bytes"; reverse      D4, C9, E3
$c = join "", @b;             # Join them.                    D4C9E3
$c .= "0000";                 # Append two NULs               D4C9E30000
$d = hex($c) % 999999929;     # Convert from hex to number and modulus
print "$d\n";                 # Print the result (in decimal).
```

Slightly clearer:

```
$a = $ARGV[0];
$a =~ s/[^0-9A-Fa-f]+//g;
$a = join '', reverse $a =~ /(..)/sg;
$a .= "0000";
$a = hex($a);
$a %= 999999929;
print "$a\n";
```

---

There might be a bug in these snippets. On a Perl with 32-bit ints, `hex` will overflow if the input has more than four hex digits. A Perl with 64-bit ints will handle 12 hex digits.

---

You seem to have taken the code from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vbgeneral/thread/a66f033e-2255-4678-9f79-a503c601d765). It's meant to take a MAC address as input, meaning the code requires 64-bit integers or [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::BigInt) to work. There's no way around it since you want to modulus a 64-bit value.

---

Here's a concise way to do it that only works on Perls with 64-bit integers:

```
my $mac = $ARGV[0];
$mac =~ s/[^0-9A-Fa-f]+//g;
die length($mac) != 12;

# "123456789ABC" => 0xBC9A785634120000
my $hash = unpack('Q<', pack('H*', "0000$mac"));

$hash %= 999999929;
print "$hash\n";
```

For portability, you're better off integrating Math::BigInt into the earlier version.

Comment: Added comment about a possible bug.

Comment: Added comment about requirements.

Comment: Ha, so I'm not the only person trying to adapt this Perl script!  That's funny.  Well you have the most concise post here [you could be a teacher] so I'm granting yours as the accepted solution.  It really helps a lot, thanks.

Comment: Added more concise code that only works on Perls with 64-bit ints.

Answer (score 2):

It's looking for a bunch octets in hex concatenated together as the first argument of the program, and applying modulus.

So, if the program is invoked as:

```
$ myprog.pl A0B0
```

then the value in `$c` will be `B0A00000`. Therefore, the value of `$d` should be `0x396A6C8E`.

It is a particularly bad piece of code written by someone who is scared of [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and  [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html).

Comment: `pack` wouldn't be too useful here (would make the code longer) unless the input has a fixed width.

Comment: @ikegami My gut tells me the code expects `$ARGV[0]` to contain 16 bit integers in little endian.

Comment: Actually, it expects a MAC address, but that's also fixed-width. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = $ARGV[0]; # assign first command line arg to $a
$a =~ s/[^A-F0-9]+//simg; # delete non-hex from $a
@b = reverse split /(\S{2})/,$a; # split $a by 2 non-whitespace (saving them too) to array  @b and reverse it
$c = join "", @b; # join array @b to scalar $c
$c .= "0000"; # append 4 zeros to $c
$d = hex($c) % 999999929; # get modulo
print "$d\n"; # print it
```

Comment: By the time of the `split` call, the string contains only hex digits. Therefore, the `split` splits the string into hex representation of octets.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Made some edits, hope it is clear now, thank you.

Comment: That second line wasn't so scary after all then!  Haha...  Thanks for your work on this.  I'm still looking over it, might still have some questions later...

Comment: So if my input is ABCDEF then array @b after the split would contain (B,A),(D,C),(F,E) ?

Comment: @armani: No, reverse in list context reverses elements order not elements themselves: ABCDEF -> qw(EF, CD, AB)

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = $ARGV[0]; #Read in the first argument on the command line
$a =~ s/[^A-F0-9]+//simg; #Substitute non hex numbers with nothing *
@b = reverse split /(\S{2})/,$a; #What is left in $a, split by 2 non-space characters
$c = join "", @b; # put the array b into $c
$c .= "0000"; 
$d = hex($c) % 999999929; #Convert $c to an integer and % with 999999929
print "$d\n";
```

- simg = i: case insensitive; g: global; m: multi-line; s: single-line;

In short, we are stripping off the first hex number, then reversing the order of bytes (2 hex numbers at a time) and doing a modulo on the result.

Comment: That explanation of "simg" -- I couldn't find that anywhere online!  I guess it's not a "basic" regex

Comment: The regexp removes any non hex characters, not what you propose.